# How can I align two curly brackets for multiple equations?

Tags: equations, align, brackets

I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

But I can't find a way to align the two brackets. It always looks like this:

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}
  \left. \begin{array}{r}
    x1 + x2 \leq 5
  \end{array} \right\}
  \text{Equation 1 says ..}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \left. \begin{array}{r}
    x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 \leq 5
  \end{array} \right\}
  \text{Equation 2 says ..}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/96172) (minimal working example)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Instead of a code snippet a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) starting with `\documentclass`, loading all needed packages (but only those) with `\usepackage` and with a document body from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}` would be useful. Without I would say, `array` is not needed in the example, but using something line `align` or `alignat` and putting both equations into one such environment would be useful.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the code snippet provided, you don't need to separate the equations. Instead, set them as part of the same `align`ment and use a forced bracket resizing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & x_1 + x_2 \leq 5 & \quad & \Big\}~
    \text{Equation 1 says \ldots} \\
  & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \leq 5 & \quad & \Big\}~
    \text{Equation 2 says \ldots}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

You can play around with the size `\Big`, even stretching it using `\vphantom`.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{lcl}
    x1 + x2 \leq 5 & \} & \text{Equation 1 says ..}\\
    x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 \leq 5 & \} & \text{Equation 2 says \dots}
   \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two other solutions: one with `eqparbox` and the `drcases`envitonment, from `mathtools`. I define an `\eqmathbox` command,  with accepts as an optional argument a `tag` (`Eq` by default), and a mandatory argument, set in mathmode, display style. All boxes sharing the same tag will have the width of the largest content of these boxes.

The other solution is based on  `blkarray`, and its `\Right{delimiter}{some text}` command (to be used in the preamble of `blocks`).

Note there's visually a difference between these solutions: the length of the text after the right brace, in the `blkarray` solution, is not taken into account for centring, as though `some text` were, really, `\rlap{some text}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, eqparbox, blkarray}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][Eq]{\eqparbox{#1}{$\displaystyle#2$}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{drcases*}
    \eqmathbox{x₁ + x₂ \leq 5}
  \end{drcases*}\quad\text{Equation 1 says \ldots} \\[2ex]
  \begin{drcases*}
    \eqmathbox{ x₁ + x₂ + x₃ + x₄ + x₅ \leq 5 d\quad}
  \end{drcases*}\quad\text{Equation 2 says \ldots}
\end{align*}

\[
  \begin{blockarray}{l}
    \begin{block}{@{}l<{\quad}\Right{\}\quad}{Equation 1 says \ldots}}
      x₁ + x₂ \leq 5 \\
    \end{block}
    \\
    \begin{block}{@{}l<{\quad}\Right{\}\quad}{Equation 2 says \ldots}}
      x₁ + x₂ + x₃ + x₄ + x₅ \leq 5 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]